# How to use read with while in stopwatch together

Tags: bash

I decided to make a simple stopwatch and found this code in the sources `stackowerflow` but I have a problem with read command. How to make the stopwatch work simultaneously with input (read)? So that the stopwatch displays time, but a little lower was an invitation to enter.

```
START=$(date +%s)

while true; do
        NOW=$(date +%s)
        DIFF=$(( $NOW - $START ))
        SECS=$(( $DIFF % 60 ))
        MIN=$(( $DIFF / 60 ))
        HOURS=$(( $DIFF / 3600 ))

        printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" $HOURS $MIN $SECS
        sleep 1

        read -p "Stop/Reset -> " INT
done
```

This code displays 1 second and then asks for input `Stop/Reset ->`, but how to make the stopwatch continue to work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Having a shell script do two things at once is not altogether trivial. I guess you could run the timer in a separate process and then just take care to not overwrite its output in the main program. See `tput` and friends for how to output screen control codes; maybe read up on `curses`.

Comment: `Any ideas?` - run the "outputting 1 second" job as background process and run `read` as you foreground process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `-t` option of read. Like this

```
START=$(date +%s)

while true; do
        NOW=$(date +%s)
        DIFF=$(( $NOW - $START ))
        SECS=$(( $DIFF % 60 ))
        MIN=$(( $DIFF / 60 ))
        HOURS=$(( $DIFF / 3600 ))

        printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" $HOURS $MIN $SECS

        # -t 1 wait at max 1 second for a key to be pressed
        # -n 1 only expect one character (no enter required)
        read -t 1 -n 1 -p "Stop/Reset -> " ANS
        if [[ "${ANS}" == "s" ]] ; then
           break
        fi
        if [[ "${ANS}" == "r" ]] ; then
           START=$(date +%s)
        fi
done
```

Comment: Where does `${INT}` value come from?

Comment: Thanks for the note. I renamed INT to ANS and obviously didn't do that everywhere.